# Linq join with Many to Many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm using MVC, C# and EntityFramework.

I've seen different solutions on Many to Many joins and after a lot of tinkering I got it to work in Linqpad. But when I try it in my solution I get an error because one of the tables isn't in my DBContext.

I have two visible tables and one hidden. Items, Recipes & RecipeItems.

All recipes are based on one item and use two or more items to be made. 
So I want a list, IEnumerable or similar with the data from both Items and Recipes that specifies this recipe and then I want all the items needed to make the recipe.

The following query works in LinqPad

```
var t = from r in Recipes
join i in Items on r.ItemId equals i.Id
select new {FinalProduct = r.FinalProduct, Effect= i.Effect, 
Description = r.Description, Ingredients = r.RecipeItems.Select(g => g.Item)};
```

When I do this in my solution I get the error since my DBContext only contains Recipe and Items but no RecipeItems. Entityframework handles this without me I guess.

I tried to make a `DbSet<RecipeItems>` without any luck. Any of you who have a suggestion of how I can move forward.

Item Class

```
  public class Item
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Effect { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipe { get; set; }
  }
```

Recipe Class

```
public class Recipe
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Final Product")]
    public string FinalProduct { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public RecipeGroup RecipeGroup { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Ingredients { get; set; }
  }
```

The ItemId in Recipe is to set the actual Item the Recipe will make.

Comment: well you have to bring in the ReceipeItems to the context. However you've introduced the `Items` and `Recipes` you'll have to do the same for the `RecipeItems`

Comment: @user12345 No, EF can handle a hidden junction table.

Comment: Please show the classes, `Item`, `Recipe`. What navigation properties do you have there? Also, how would you make the distinction between the "base" item and the other items?

Comment: @GertArnold I edited the post to add the classes hope that helps.

Comment: @GertArnold I wasn't aware of that as I haven't really used EF that much. Do I understand this correctly that it allows to join to tables that are not specified in the context? Wouldn't that just invalidate all sort of security measures or am I missing something very obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Recipe object:

```
public Recipe()
{
        this.Ingredients = new HashSet<Item>();
}
```

This overrides the default constructor for the class and kind of gives EF a place that initializes the related objects.